# Before Insert trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Possuo um cadastro que no insert a data informada precisa ser a data atual, e não pode ser alterada futuramente porque é um dos requisitos.

Esse bloqueio será feito por uma trigger.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TESTE."TBI_AD_SAC" 
   BEFORE INSERT 
   ON AD_SAC FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       :NEW.DATAHORA := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
   END;
```

sera informado uma mensagem que a data nao pode ser alterada, mas o bloqueio deve ocorrer na trigger.

Comment: Uma solução Trigger de validação de before update se o campo mudar dá um raise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330884/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-make-a-column-readonly-in-oracle

Comment: e qual é a dúvida? já tem a lógica (trigger), o que precisa? é como fazer isso na trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TESTE."TBI_AD_SAC" 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON AD_SAC FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF INSERTING THEN /*verbo*/
          :NEW.DATAHORA := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
        ELSIF UPDATING THEN /*verbo*/
          IF :NEW.DATAHORA <> :OLD.DATAHORA THEN
            raise_application_error(-20111,'DATAHORA NAO E EDITAVEL !!');
          END IF;
        END IF;
    END;
```

Obs
**Raise** força um erro na alteração de DATAHORA
**inserting e updating** "verbos" que permitem saber a operação.

Dúvida que pode ser de interesse de outros.

https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/oracle-raise_application_error/

https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/oracle-trigger/

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0560__Trigger/INSERTINGDELETINGandUPDATINGPredicates.htm